# Element stays on the top when the page is scrolled down, but always under the header

Tags: html, css, sticky

Please see this jsfiddle here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/q5JpH/).

I want the red element on the right to stay always on top, but never cover the header. So when the page is not scrolled down it is somewhere, for example 200px from top. When I scroll down and the top of the window touches it, it comes down along with the page, glued to the top. The code I used is here:

```
<header>header</header>
<div class="overflow">
    <div class="left">
        Some content here, doesn't matter what... 
    </div>

    <aside>
        This is a key element
    </aside>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
body {margin:0; padding:0}
header {width:100%; height:200px; background-color:#994499; margin-bottom:30px;}
.overflow {overflow:hidden; width:450px; margin:0 auto;}
.left {float:left; width:300px; background-color:yellow; margin-right:20px; height:1000px;}
aside {position:fixed; top:230px; margin-left:350px; background-color:red;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "sticky navbar" technique for this functionality, if you don't mind jQuery.

The trick being to absolutely/relatively position the element opposed to fixed, then apply a fixed class on scroll.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhLpK/2/)

```
$(function () {
    var elem = $('aside'),
        elemTop = elem.offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        elem.toggleClass('fixed', $(window).scrollTop() > elemTop);
    }).scroll();
});
```

Comment: thanks @KennyGHanson - that's exactly what I was after! Well done

Comment: Your code can be written in a substantially smaller way - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhLpK/2/).

Comment: Thank you @fabrício-matté. I have updated my answer with the suggested code as well as the fiddle link. I am still learning so I greatly appreciate your comment.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, my rewrite was mostly an example of what you can do, in fact, your previous function declaration + function call was technically slightly faster than my `.scroll()` which has the overhead of creating and dispatching a `scroll` event. Talking about performance, it is also possible to cache the `$(window)` object like you did with `elem`. Well, these would be mostly just micro-optimizations which would hardly ever make any noticeable difference anyway.